# l3build - Work directly with a documentation as a `PDF` file

Tags: documentation, l3build

To work with `l3build`, I want to use the following structure where I give the documentation directly in the form of a `PDF` file.

```
.
├── MANIFEST.md
├── README.md
├── build.lua
├── code
│   ├── bdoc-locale-english.cfg.sty
│   ├── bdoc-locale-french.cfg.sty
│   └── bdoc.sty
├── doc
│   └── bdoc-fr.pdf
└── testfiles
    ├── write-macro-n-pack.lvt
    └── write-macro-n-pack.tlg
```

How do I tell to `l3build` that my documentation is the `bdoc-en.pdf` file?
This implies that this file will be placed in the doc files TDS.

**NOTE.**
The `bdoc-en.pdf` file can be placed in the `code` folder as long as this file will be well placed in the TDS structure.

Comment: If you do this, your package will get rejected (or partially rejected) by Linux distributions such as Debian. I don't know what TeX Live's current policy on this is, but they are stricter than they used to be partly in order to enable support in major Linux distros. Debian (and others) reject non-free documentation just as they reject non-free software. Not all Linux distros are this strict, but Debian is not alone and that's a good proportion of the Linux world considering all the Debian derivatives. Fedora is similarly strict.

Comment: I've deliberately simplified the structure of the sources: what concerns me here is the PDF documentation. There will be a licence file when the project will be distributed, at least to protect me in case of misuse.

Comment: My point is that if you distribute the documentation solely in compiled form, it will be rejected as non-free. It isn't a question of licence. It won't meet the conditions for inclusion in distributions which use only free software such as Debian, Fedora and derivatives.

Comment: I don't intend this as a criticism. It's your project ;). It's just a FYI, since people who write packages often want them to be picked up and distributed as part of TeX Live and MikTeX etc. and you may not be aware of the consequences of withholding source for the documentation.

Comment: I don't see that as a criticism. ;-) In that case, I'll work on providing documentation with its sources. A bit of `Python` coding on top of that, but it'll be easy. Thanks for saving me a lot of tears :-) during distribution.

Comment: @cfr If I understand correctly, I must therefore also avoid producing documentation using images.

Comment: I think it depends if the image is itself the source. So if you take a photo or something, I think the jpeg is probably OK because there's no separate source. But if you made an image in GIMP or Inkscape they'd want the source file. It's a while since I read up on this, though, so you might want to check. But it isn't meant to make it impossible to include a file of type X. It's supposed to enable somebody else to modify X in the same way you can. So if you made an image in Inkscape, I think they'd want SVG and not just PDF.

Comment: @cfr I'll make a note of it. I'll keep my images for demos and limit my documentations to codes that can be compiled directly using LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to list the file in `docfiles`

```lua
module = "demo"
docfiledir = "doc"
docfiles = {"bdoc-fr.pdf"}
```

Comment: Great, and sorry for all my last question about `l3build`. :-)

Comment: A suggestion: the `l3build` documentation should organize by category tables on page 10 and the following ones.

Comment: @projetmbc They are grouped already: the need to worry about `.dtx` files, etc., means there isn't a simple separation between targets.